# how to change my date picker show in only month,date ,year, and time

Tags: iphone

The default UIDatePicker shows both the date and time. I need to show only the month, day, year and time like this

[image]

How can I change the date picker to this?

Answer (score 1):

Well First off I suggest reading through the [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) documentation. Here are the Date Picker Modes:

```
Date Picker Mode
The mode of the date picker.

typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

If you cannot find what you need there. Then you can create your own by using a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).